# struts2 mysql conection error in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am connecting to MySQL using JDBC to the JSP, but it shows error `classNotFoundException` in eclipse in struts JSP page.

validate.java:

```
package com.demo;
import java.sql.*;  
public class LoginValidate {

    public boolean validateLogin(){
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inspioqj_appointment");
        return true;    
    }
}
```

Same code using in same project  jsp file its working what is problem i am not understanding.

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> There is home page.</p>
<hr/>  
<a href="login">login</a>|  
<a href="logout">logout</a>|  
<a href="profile">profile</a> 
<%

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inspioqj_appointment");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I have included MySQL java connector on lib folder in eclipse struts project, but it is not working in action controller validate.java but it *is* working in index.jsp page.

What is problem?  I could not understand.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Add mysql jconnector jar in your project.

Comment: check if u are not using eclipse, then add jar using build path .

Answer (score 0):

Its a pretty simple ClassNotFoundException. Make sure that the mySQL jar is present in the class-path of the project as well. You can do this by right-clicking the project, configure class-path and from there you can add the particular jar

Comment: please can you specify all step how to add classpath.I have added mysql jar inside web-info/lib directory and  also java buildPAth->libraries.But still showing error classNotFoundException.

Comment: build-path -> libraries is the actual method of adding a particular jar to the build path of the project. If you have done that and still you are getting the ClassNotFoundException then there is a possibility that the required classes are not in your class-path (other than mysql)